# move_uploaded_file error

Tags: php

I was writing a form for uploading photos but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="akcija.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Ucitaj" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
?php
$fileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$path = "/htdocs/";
$newFilePlace = $path . $fileName;
$tmpname = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
echo $fileName . "    nejm" . "<br/>" ;
echo $newFilePlace . "<br/>";
echo $tmpname . " hej <br/>";



if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $newFilePlace)) {
echo "ERROR";
}


?>
```

Output:

> 800px-Juan_Manuel_Santos_and_Lula_(cropped).jpg nejm
>
> /htdocs/800px-Juan_Manuel_Santos_and_Lula_(cropped).jpg /tmp/phpAQPhC7
>
> hej  ERROR

Comment: More than likely something to do with file permissions, are you on hosted servers?

Comment: `/htdocs/`, with that leading `/` implies a folder in the root of your system. Most likely that folder doesn't exist there and/or you don't have access to that. You probably want to write to your document root, which is likely something like `/var/bladiebla/accountid/website/htdocs` or so. The better option would be to use a relative path, relative to the current file,

Comment: Yes, I am using hosted server, but I can create files in that folder with fopen(), so i suppose it is writable

Comment: I used relative path and now it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Only add the root path of folder and create a folder name htdocs inside the folder where the file is.

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$fileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$path = SITE_ROOT;  // for root folder 
$path1 = SITE_ROOT . "foldername"; // for specific folder
$newFilePlace = $path . $fileName;
$tmpname = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
echo $fileName . "    nejm" . "<br/>" ;
echo $newFilePlace . "<br/>";
echo $tmpname . " hej <br/>";

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $newFilePlace)) {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

**This is tested and working fine for me**

Answer (score 0):

ok you sould use the path as empty string if you want to upload the file to htdocs keeping in mind that your file also exists on the htdocs directory. This code works fine for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $fileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $path = "";
    $newFilePlace = $path . $fileName;
    $tmpname = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    echo $fileName . "    nejm" . "<br/>" ;
    echo $newFilePlace . "<br/>";
    echo $tmpname . " hej <br/>";



    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $newFilePlace)) {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}

?>
```